# print recursive list in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to print a recursive list where every date has a sublist of events ordered by date.

For example on the database I have:

```
+------+----------+--------+
| date | event_id | post_id|
+------+----------+--------+
|date1 | event1   | post1  |
|date1 | event2   | post2  |
|date1 | event3   | post3  |
|date2 | event4   | post4  |
|date2 | event5   | post5  |
+------+----------+--------+
```

I need to print

```
<ul>
    <li>date1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>event1, post1</li>
        <li>event2, post2</li>
        <li>event3, post3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Date 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>event4, post4</li>
        <li>event5, post5</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

how can I print in php the

```
select date, event_id, post_id from tablename
```

query in php to have this?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086541/how-do-i-group-same-array-value

Comment: hmm, transforming the query result array in a more html friendly one is indeed elegant (but more memory intensive, if that is a concern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while with php and mysql, I do the least I can in mysql, even if it's often more elegant. Performance of mysql is crap. And even if what you query is fast, it can still slow down another query elsewhere done by another user. So here is a response with the least load on the DB. One query, no grouping. just select your 3 fields, and you can apply this.

```
$lastDate = null;  // lastDate will be updated at each row, so we can check if it has changed the next one.

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($queryResult as $row)
{
    if ( $lastDate != $row['date'] )
    {
        if ( $lastDate) { echo '</ul>'; }  // if lastdate "exists", it's not the first, so let't close the "date" list...

        echo '<li>', $row['date'], '</li><ul>'; // ... and start a new one
    }
    echo '<li>', $row['event_id'], ', ',$row['post_id'], '</li>';
    $lastDate = $row['date'];  

}
echo '</ul>'; // close the very last date list
echo '</ul>'; // close the the full list
```

Comment: This works only if `$queryResult` is ordered by the `date` column. Thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: absolutely! It's implicitly implied it was implicit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT   date,
         GROUP_CONCAT(event_id) AS 'event_ids',
         GROUP_CONCAT(post_id) AS 'post_ids'
FROM     tablename
GROUP BY date
```

This will return results with three fields. `date` will be the date field, `event_ids` and `post_ids` will be comma separated lists of the events and posts that fall under that date.

Comment: so you will have to print result $rows like "date1" / "event1, event2" / "post1, post2". Splitting the line so carefully concatenated is no  fun. However, `select concat("<li>", date, "</li>"), concat("<ul>", GROUP_CONCAT(concat("<li>", event_id, ", ", post_id, "</li>")), "</ul>")
FROM tablename
GROUP BY date` shall do it, if I didn't mix parenthesis ("add Comment" is quite a lousy editor X'D)

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You'd want to add some error checking though.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query(SELECT date FROM tableName);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ($dateRow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<li>" . $dateRow['date'] . "</li>";
            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT event_id,post_id FROM tableName where date = '" . $dateRow['date'] . "'");
            if (mysql_num_row($result2) > 0)
            {   
                echo "<ul>";
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    echo "<li>" . $row['event_id'] . " , " . $row['post_id'] . "</li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: an sql query in a php loop? please *anything* but that!

Answer (score 1):

The following is a rough answer:

```
$query = "select date, event_id, post_id from tablename order by date";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$currentDate = null;

echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     if($currentDate != $row['date']){
          echo "<li>" . $currentDate  . "</li>";
          echo "<ul>";
     }

     echo "<li>" . $row['event'] . $row['post'] . "</li>";

     if($currentDate != $row['date']){
          $currentDate = $row['date'];
          echo "</ul>";
     }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the problem. First of all, you should nest the unordered list items into parent elements. The resulting output should be

```html
<ul>
    <li>date1
        <ul>
            <li>event1, post1</li>
            <li>event2, post2</li>
            <li>event3, post3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Date 2
        <ul>
            <li>event4, post4</li>
            <li>event5, post5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Advantages** of this nested schema:

- valid html (this alone is good enough)
- easier DOM-manipulation by Javascript

Here's a function which in theory should output the former html:

```
function printList()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT t.event_id, t.post_id, t.date FROM table t ORDER BY date';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $date = null;
    $out = '';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if($date !== $row['date'])
        {
            if(!is_null($date))
            {
                $out .= '</ul></li>';
            }

            $date = $row['date'];

            $out .= sprintf('<li>%s<ul>', $row['date']);
        }

        $out.= sprintf('<li>%s, %s</li>', $row['event_id'], $row['post_id']);            
    }

    return sprintf('<ul>%s</ul></li></ul>', $out);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT date, event_id, post_id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date";
```

Comment: group by with non aggregating function on the non group functions will give you the first value, ignoring other (If my memory is correct, it's like 20 years I didn't try that). tl; dr one event and post only by date.