# PHP - grouping arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$Show = [];

foreach ($result_radio as $Station => $Show){
$Show [] = array($result_radio[$Station]['StationID'] => $Show); }
```

`var_dump($Show)` //outputs

```
array(19771) { // Number of Shows accross 182 Station

[0]=> array(1) { [24315]=> array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"24315" ["Show"]=> "JaazOnline" ["Genre"]=> "Jazz" ...
[1]=> array(1) { [24315]=> array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"24315" ["Show"]=> "Jaaz24/7" ["Genre"]=> "Jazz" ..
[2]=> array(1) { [24315]=> array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"24315" ["Show"]=> "JazzUsa" ["Genre"]=> "Jazz" ...
[3]=> array(1) { [66995]=> array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"66995" ["Show"]=> "StateofTrance" ["Genre"]=> "Electronic" ..
[4]=> array(1) { [66995]=> array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"66995" ["Show"]=> "ElectroHouse" ["Genre"]=> "Electronic"...
```

This returns an array of 19771 Radio Shows as arrays where `$key` is the **StationID** and Value `$Show` related information about this specific Show.

This is what I wanted, but I would like to format my array in a way instead to have only one array for each StationID and within all shows that belong to this ID

***for example e.g***

```
array(182) {  // 182 Radio Stations

[24315]=>  array(50) {  //Shows classified by Station Id

             array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"24315" ["Show"]=> "JaazOnline" ["Genre"]=> "Jazz" ...
             array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"24315" ["Show"]=> "Jaaz24/7" ["Genre"]=> "Jazz" ..
             array(16) { ["StationID"]=>"24315" ["Show"]=> "JazzUsa" ["Genre"]=> "Jazz" ...



[66995]=>  array(32) { 

             array(16) {["StationID"]=>"66995" ["Show"]=> "StateofTrance" ["Genre"]=> "Electronic" 
             array(16) {["StationID"]=>"66995" ["Show"]=> "ElectroHouse" ["Genre"]=> "Electronic"
```

Why? 
Because I think it makes my life easier client side to access objects properties this way.. Please any some help formatting this array of shows in a way to have ONE index representing a Station ID and within all shows...

Comment: Why the downvote? I gave a specific example and I was trying by myself. If I know the answer I wouldn't be here...

Comment: You can create another array grouped by same key

Comment: And I am not asking for a complete code solution but hints .... some people think they are born knowing everything

Comment: @ronit, within the $result_radio foreach loop ?

Comment: yah something like that if keys are similar push to new array

Comment: this link will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086541/how-do-i-group-same-array-value

Comment: Thanks thats great example, thanks Ronit will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
$Show = array();
foreach ($result_radio as $Station => $Show){
$Show [$result_radio[$Station]['StationID']][] = $Show; }
```

It should do exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 Yes, this should be it. Beat me to it by a few seconds. OP, try this and report back if it doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Thank you both indeed it returns an array of 182 arrays where each key represents the ID. it worth to mention, the link provided by Ronit is also an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can also write a function like:

```
function _group_by($array, $key) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $val) {
        $return[$val[$key]][] = $val;
    }
    return $return;
}
```